# Is this the right way to use queries in the Firestore from Android Jetpack ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an application in android studio, using "navigation component architecture" in addition to using MVVM, for this, is it correct to make inquiries to Firestore in the ViewModels of the fragments?

```java
public class ProfileViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> name;
    private MutableLiveData<String> lastName;


    public ProfileViewModel() {
        name= new MutableLiveData<>();
        lastName= new MutableLiveData<>();

    }

    public void saveToFirestore(){
        FirebaseFirestore db  =FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.document( PATH )
                .set( OBJECT )
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });

    }

}
```

Comment: From a Java perspective, you can take a look at another [approach](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreRealtimePagination) which is a repo for this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firestore-pagination-with-real-time-updates-ce05a87bb902). You'll be able to see how you can make a LiveData work together with a ViewModel and a Repository.

Comment: @AlexMamo your provided example has lots of bug.

Comment: @Pooja I'll recheck that out.

Comment: @AlexMamo you also replied to someone that you will, before two months 

Comment: @Pooja I need to find some time for that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it is not correct to make database queries in a ViewModel.  ViewModel should consult a "repository" type object for the actual database query.  ViewModel is responsible for converting objects there to something suitable for interaction by a View.

You might want to take a look at my sample project that uses MVVM with Firestore using Jetpack components.  It doesn't include any examples of writing data, but the patter holds that ViewModel does not know data store implementation details.

https://github.com/CodingDoug/firebase-jetpack

Comment: Hi Doug, thank you for the code and Youtube presentation. That is a very important topic. Since then, is there any change in firebase recommendation for MVVM implementation? Are there any plans to make a more generic solution? since it seems quite complex to maintain, specially for the smaller projects. Thx.

Comment: @DougStevenson is this github repository available in Java?